# How can I get access token and store it from signin-oidc on client side ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: angular, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have 3 projects

1) **Identity Server**. It's netcoreapp1.1 and identityserver4. Its URL is http://localhost:9000

Here is my configuration for the client app.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "customer.api",
                ClientName = "Customer services",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris = validClientUris.CustomerClientUris
                    .Select(baseUri => baseUri + "signin-oidc")
                    .ToList(),
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = validClientUris.CustomerClientUris.ToList(),

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("testsecret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    HydraScopes.CustomerPrivateLinesVNApi, //"customerprivatelinesvn.api"                       
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AllowedCorsOrigins = validClientUris.CustomerClientUris
            });
```

2) **REST API project**. It's ASP.NET Core 2.0. Its URL is http://localhost:60001

Here is ConfigureServices of Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddCustomerManagementCoreServices()
            .AddRavenStoreServices(Configuration);

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // "Bearer"
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:9000/";
                options.ApiName = "customerprivatelinesvn.api";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

        services.AddMvc(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;                
        });

        services.AddApiVersioning(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });            
    }
```

3) **Angular web application**. Its URL is http://localhost:60002

I use the Angular template of Visual Studio 2017 as below.
[image]

Here is ConfigureServices of Startup class of Angular web

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();            

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "Cookies"
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "OpenIdConnect"
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "Cookies"
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(options);                
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

And here is the configuration of OpenIdConnect

```
"OpenIdConnect": {
"Authority": "http://localhost:9000/",
"RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
"ClientId": "customer.api",
"ClientSecret": "testsecret",
"Scope": [ "customerprivatelinesvn.api", "offline_access" ],      
"PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:60002",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"ResponseType": "code id_token token",
"GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": true,
"SaveTokens":  true}
```

With configurations above, when user browses to Angular web (http://localhost:60002), it will redirect to the login page of Identity Server. After user inputs username/password, it will return to Angular app with authenticated information stored in cookies (http://localhost:60002).

I believe that the access token is stored in the cookies as well. Because I can see it in Fiddler at localhost:60002/signin-oidc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have some questions

**1) How can I get access token from cookies so that I can add it to the request header to be able to call REST API on Angular components?**

**2) Can we store access token to Local Storage instead of Cookies? And how to store?**

**3) How can I store and use refresh token to get new access token when access token expired?**

Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Kevin

Comment: It's easy to get access token. I can resolve it now.

Comment: I have the same problem. Couldn't solve this, Kevin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can call HttpContext.GetTokenAsync() in the view

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <input id="access_token" type="hidden" value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result" />    
}
```

Or we can store the access token in LocalStorage

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script>
        var key = "My_app_Access_Token";
        var accessToken = document.getElementById("access_token");
        localStorage.setItem(key, accessToken.value);
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I got this error: 'AuthenticationManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetTokenAsync' and no extension method 'GetTokenAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you have to add using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication